# Can I leave the Helsinki airport on a layover, as an American

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, layovers, finland, hel

I have a 24 hr layover in Helsinki. I am traveling in a US passport. Can I leave the airport, check into a hotel, and take a bus into the city?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can. Finland is part of the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area), which means US passport holders may enter without requiring a visa for up to 90 days within any 180 day period.